# Why Misra showing error " Integral promotion : unsigned char promoted to signed int" in Condition check?

Tags: c, integer, static-analysis, misra

I am trying to fix the MISRA error for a small function which will compare two unsigned integer values. But i think, i have done the typecasting properly.

```
static void check_counter(void)
{
  uint8 counter = 0x00U;

  (void) get_updatecounterval(&counter);

  if(counter < (uint8) 0xFF)
  {
     counter++;
  } 
  else
  {
    counter = 0x00U;
  }
}
```

During the MISRA check, I am getting the below errors

```
if(counter < (uint8) 0xFF) //  Integral promotion : unsigned char promoted to signed int
{
  counter++;        // Integral promotion : unsigned char promoted to signed int
}
```

I have tried to fix this error by typecasting below

```
if((uint8)counter < (uint8) 0xFF)
{
  counter++; 
}
```

But I am getting the same error. What is the problem here? Some help to fix this error?

Comment: Types smaller than `int` are always promoted to `int` before use in an arithmetic operator.  That's inherent to C.  Casting can't fix it because the promotion would just be applied to the casted value.  Why MISRA thinks it's a problem, or what they expect you to do instead, I don't know.

Comment: Maybe they expect you to cast both sides to `unsigned int` instead?  That way the promotion no longer applies, and you can be sure that the arithmetic will be done in an unsigned fashion as you probably intended.

Comment: @NateEldredge Please don't confuse the requirements from MISRA C with what some broken MISRA C checker claims to be relevant warnings.

Comment: Brief googling seems to suggest that these are general QAC warnings and not part of the MISRA check... so just disable them and focus on MISRA compliance?

Comment: @Lundin Is that pronounced "quack"? :-)

Answer (score 3):

The only minor MISRA violation you have in that function is that `0xFF` should be `0xFFu`/`0xFFU`.

Otherwise regarding integer promotions, the most relevant MISRA C:2012 rules here are 10.1 and particularly 10.4. Where 10.4 says that both operands of the `<` should have the same essential type category, in this case "unsigned". So your code is fine.

You can also write `if(counter < 0xFFu)` and that's fine too. Both operands are essentially unsigned.

There is no MISRA rule "Integral promotion: unsigned char promoted to signed int", this is something your tool is spitting out as extra diagnostics, unrelated to MISRA. A proper MISRA diagnostic message would list the number of the rule violated.

Also the text "integral" rather than "integer" suggests this is for MISRA C:2004 and C90, both are quite outdated. MISRA C:2004 didn't have "essential type" but required the result of expressions to be cast to an "underlying type", which wasn't a very good rule, but still doesn't explain the warnings you got.

Comment: All agreed... :-)